# int() is not working properly

Tags: python, int, rounding

I try this code with python 2.7.9:

```
a=8.52
for i in range(1,3):
    a *= 10.0
    print int (a)
```

It should display

```
85
852
```

But it displays

```
85
851
```

Do you have any idea why? Is it a known bug?

Comment: `a*10` is `85.19999999999999` .

Comment: @Zach, it's worth nothing you'll almost guaranteed never find a bug in the language if you're just starting out. The language is very mature in that sense.

Comment: I understand the closing of this often asked question, but I think the downvotes are harsh.  OP thought the problem was with `int` and was thus poorly prepared to Google for the correct terms that would lead to an answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski perspective was the reason I answered: first, giving OP the chance to google himself, and secondly, providing the typical debugging steps

Answer (score 4):

> Do you have any idea why? Is it a known bug?

The obvious `print` debugging approach yields:

```
a=8.52
for i in range(1,3):
    a *= 10.0
    print int (a)
print a
```

which prints:

```
85
851
851.99999...
```

So, what's happening here is *floating point math*. It's not *exact*, because there's no exact way to represent `8.51` with binary floating point. Instead, a value very very close (yet smaller) to `8.51` is first stored in `a`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if I print "int(a*100)" I get "852". Shouldn't it be the same result? (also if I add "print a" at the end I obtain "852" instead of "851.999...")

Comment: No, it shouldn't be the same result.

Comment: and if you get 852 at the end, then your python 2.7.9 is a) broken and b) behaves different from my python 2.7.9.